# How to access a MainWindow variable from a page in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to code a WPF desktop Application. Currently i have a Main Window **(MainWindow)** and a page **(Pageone)** under the same solution. From my **MainWindow.xaml.cs** page, i have a variable **(proc1)** which i want to pass to my **Pageone.xaml.cs** page and maybe even more pages in the future to access and use for some calculation.

However i cant seem to find a method to successfully do this, i have tried making my variable **"public"**, and instantiate the **MainWindow** object for my page to access it but it doesn't seem to work. `(A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Pageone.pog')`

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public string proc1;

public void startTroubleshootButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var selectedProcess = listViewProcesses.SelectedItems[0] as myProcess;
                if (selectedProcess == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("no selection made");
                    return;
                }

                proc1 = selectedProcess.processName;

                MessageBox.Show($"you have selected the {proc1} application ");

                Pageone pg = new Pageone(this);
                this.Content = pg;


            }
            catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

**Pageone.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class Pageone : Page
    {

        public Pageone(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
        }
        MainWindow pog = new MainWindow();
        string procName = pog.proc1;

     ...
```

I've heard that i will maybe need to use something called the MVVM or code a parameterized constructor but i'm not sure if its related to the code i'm doing. Is there a better way to go about coding this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done like:

```
var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```